# Pandas: Finding first condition in a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to get the first occurrence of values less than -3 in a timeseries dataset.  I am having difficulties in doing so using pandas and avoiding explicit iteration/loops.  Let's say i have the table below:

```
Date          Return
2020-10-12   -1.501909
2020-10-13   -2.123128
2020-10-14   -3.771381
2020-10-15   -4.919922
2020-10-16   -3.006824
2020-10-19   -2.492342
2020-10-20   -1.040846
2020-10-21   -2.251543
2020-10-22   -3.751839
2020-10-23   -3.420191
2020-10-26   -5.215563
2020-10-27   -2.502344
2020-10-28   -2.836966
2020-10-29   -3.747811
2020-10-30   -3.866789
```

The results im looking for is to get only first value less than -3. so the results would look like this

```
Date         Return
2020-10-14   -3.771381
2020-10-22   -3.751839
2020-10-29   -3.747811
```

Ideally it would be nice to also get the count values less than -3 in a new column

```
Date         Return     streak
2020-10-14   -3.771381  3
2020-10-22   -3.751839  3
2020-10-29   -3.747811  2
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shift` the values by one position, so you can compare at a "one-off" index.
From there, it's simply a matter of filtering with the dual condition

```
df['Return'] < -3 and df['shifted'] > -3
```

With those clues, can you handle the coding details?

Comment: This did work i think @Prune. instead of 'and' i needed to do bitwise however:  df[(df['Return'] <= -3) & (df['Return'].shift(1)>-3)]

Answer (score 0):

Yes use a filter:

```
df = df[df['Return'] < -3]
```

Comment: this returns all rows that are less than -3, not the first